# Multiplication algorithm for 24 bit numbers on MCS-51

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, multiplication

I am trying to make a program in assembly language for an [MCS-51 microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) with [this Datasheet](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Intel/MCS51/MANUALS/27238302.PDF).

It must multiply 24 bit numbers.

Maybe I ask a stupid question, but how would I multiply a column of 24 bit?

In the below pictures is illustrated the way to multiplicate 16-bit numbers. How would look the multiplication scheme for 24 bit numbers?

[image: 1pic]

[image: 2pic]

Comment: Pretty much the same way but with more partial products, you know long multiplication right?

Answer (score 4):

Based on a quick peek at the documentation, the MCS-51 has 8x8->16 multiply. You two 24-bit numbers `A` and `B`, which are equivalent to:

```
A = a0 + (a1 * 256) + (a2 * 65536)
B = b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 65536)
```

Where a0 is the lowest byte of A, a1 is the middle byte of A, a2 is the highest byte, and the bs are the corresponding things for B.

Therefore:

```
A * B = (a0 + (a1 * 256) + (a2 * 65536)) * (b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 65536))
      = a0 * (b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 65536)) +
        a1 * 256 * (b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 65536)) +
        a2 * 65536 * (b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 65536))
      = a0 * b0         + a0 * b1 * 256      + a0 * b2 * 65536 +
        a1 * b0 * 256   + a1 * b1 * 65536    + a1 * b2 * 16777216 +
        a2 * b0 * 65536 + a2 * b1 * 16777216 + a2 * b2 * 4294967296
      = a0 * b0 +
        256 * (a0 * b1 + a1 * b0) +
        65536 * (a0 * b2 + a1 * b1 + a2 * b0) +
        16777216 * (a1 * b2 + a2 * b0) +
        4294967296 * (a2 * b2)
```

So it's all nine 8x8 multiplies, then add together in groups, then shift each group as required, then add everything at the end.

If you only wanted a 24-bit result rather than a 48-bit one, you can cut everything from `16777216 *` since obviously that part can't contribute to the low three bytes. Or similarly stop doing the work elsewhere for other output sizes.